# Different HTTP POST in different class using the same methods?

Tags: java, php, android, post

I am pretty new to Android developement and Java. Currently, I have an application that makes a basic HTTP POST request with a few parameters.

I would like to know if it is possible to make 2 activities that just make the same request but with different parameters, **not having to paste the sames methods in the 2 activities**.

Example: I have two screens, identics and when I press the button on each screen it sends the post request that I made with different parameters.

PS: What I ask may not be specific enough, so just ask me for details or some code (but I don't think it's necessary here).

Edit : I think I badly explained my thougts :D
I have a class with static functions for the post :

public class MyHttpPost {

```
public static String performPostCall(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = null;
    int len = 500;
    URL url;

    try {
        url = new URL(requestURL);

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        is = conn.getInputStream();

        return readIt(is, len);

    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}

public static String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException {
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}

private static String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for( Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet() ) {

        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

}

and two activities :

public class TestPost extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";

private TextView myView;
private EditText urlText;
HashMap<String, String> postDataParams;
WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_post);

    myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
    urlText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myUrl);

    postDataParams = new HashMap<>();
    postDataParams.put("firstParam", "1234");
    postDataParams.put("secondParam", "qwerty");

    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);

    TextView editTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myText);
    String message = editTextview.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

protected class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return MyHttpPost.performPostCall(urls[0], postDataParams);
        } catch (IOException e) {
             return getResources().getString(R.string.bad_url);
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        myView.setText(result);
        webview.loadData(result, "text/html", null);
    }
}

// When user clicks button, calls AsyncTask.
// Before attempting to fetch the URL, makes sure that there is a network connection.
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
    String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
    } else {
        myView.setText("No network connection available.");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_test_post, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

and

public class OtherClass extends TestPost {

```
private TextView myView;
private EditText urlText;
HashMap<String, String> postDataParams;
WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_post);

    myView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
    urlText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myUrl);
    myView.setText("coucou");

    postDataParams = new HashMap<>();
    postDataParams.put("firstParam", "9876");
    postDataParams.put("secondParam", "ytreza");

    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
}

protected class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return MyHttpPost.performPostCall(urls[0], postDataParams);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return getResources().getString(R.string.bad_url);
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        myView.setText(result);
        webview.loadData(result, "text/html", null);
    }
}

public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    // Gets the URL from the UI's text field.
    String stringUrl = urlText.getText().toString();
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
            getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        new DownloadWebpageTask().execute(stringUrl);
    } else {
        myView.setText("No network connection available.");
    }
}
```

}

As you see, in the second class, to send different parameters, I must redefine a the functions, and I would like to know if it's the only option (and if it's not bad to do so).
Like if I could only in the two class only define the params and make the request.

Comment: Ofcourse you can run a single method with different params, thats the purpose of OOP.

Comment: You can define method(in that call http post) in different class (like util) and call that method from   different activities with different parameters

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you could do this if you create an utils class, where you can paste the methods (public and having parameters that you could pass), that are same for both activities and then call them from the activities like this: `UtilsClass.sendPOSTRequest(myparam1, myparam2);`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `NetworkService` class which contains the method to execute the HTTP POST. The method takes the parameters which are different in your requests. Then create an instance of this class and pass it to both Activities.

Your new `NetworkService` should contain all network-related methods for a better architecture, see [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Answer (score 0):

This calls for a NetworkUtils class! This will be a class you should use statically with the same HTTP POST method (the one you want to define in both activities) and call a public static method. Ex:

```
public class NetworkUtils{

    public static HttpResponse postData(String param1, String param2) {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", param1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", param2));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request, return response
            return httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStacktrace();
        }
        return null;
    }    
}
```

Check for null in case there is an issue with the network request. Other than that this is just an example of what your solution would look like. (to save extra code!)

NOTE: This method must be called WITHIN an AsyncThread or a Handler because you are blocking the UI thread when this happens.

Comment: HttpPost is deprecated in api 22. You should use `HttpUrlConnection `instead. http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html

Comment: Fair enough. His question asked for how to deal with minimizing code replication, so my example was just to show how to possibly use your preferred HTTP library in a utils class.

Comment: that is why posted this as a comment in case someone needs info

Answer (score 0):

make a global class and  define your http method/methods and make them static !! use it from anywhere and pass the parameter as you like